# Saving recursive results in r

Tags: r, loops, recursion, apply

I make some changes to the algoritm example. 
The last example missed some information. I am explaining more in detail. Probably there are some basic issues but I am not very familiar with loops.

Initial values

```
x<-matrix(c(1,1,1,1,
      -1,-1,1,1,
      -1,1,-1,1), nrow = 4)
w<-matrix(rep(0,15), nrow = 5)
d<-c(-1,1,1,1)
```

Variables

```
v <- 10L
y <- 10L
e <- 10L
des <- 10L
m <- 0.5
```

**The idea of the loop is to find values of w for every row of x until d = i .** It is more clear if you see the loop.

This loop is working well but only for the first 5 rows. It must be looping on x until the condition (d=i) is satisfied. **I know it is not the right way of doing. It is just to exemplify what I want to do.** Other options (apply) are welcome.

Loop

```
for(i in 1:4) {
# Multiplies every row of x by w. The w comes from the result of the loop.    
v[i]<- t(w[i,]) %*%  x[i,]

# Takes the sign of v.
y[i] <- if(v[i] >= 0) 1 else -1

# Value to use in the last line of the loop.
e[i] <- d[i]-y[i]

des[i] <- if(d[i] == y[i]) 1 else 0 #check if condition is satisfied 
w[i+1,] <- w[i,]+(m*e[i]*x[i,])
}
```

Desired output

```
w <- matrix(c(0,-1,0,1,1,1,1,
   0,1,0,1,1,1,1,
   0,1,2,1,1,1,1), nrow=7)
```

Comment: You code is not reproducible and produces error `Error in des[i] <- if (d[i] == y[i]) 1 else 0 : object 'des' not found`. Please provide reproducible code.

Comment: I'd enclose your loop in a function, so that you pass in w as a parameter.  You can then return whatever you want as the result of that function call -- including the new w -- without overwriting your original w.  I'm unclear if that's what you need.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF, what is `d`?

Comment: @SunBee I have just made a reproducible code. Take a look again.

Comment: @Joy I think is a good idea to pass w as a parameter. Could you take a look again to the changes in the algorithm and exemplify me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a bit messy.  It might be helpful to provide the desired output.  This is because, generally speaking, you can circumvent slow for loops when manipulating matrices.  That being said, this should help

The first problem with your code is that you are not using your initial values.  Additionally you are attempting to subset integers, for example, when `v <- 10L` `v[2]` will return `NA`.  Below I've preallocated all the parameters you later utilize.

```
itr_n <- 3
v <- rep(NA, itr_n)
y <- rep(NA, itr_n)
e <- rep(NA, itr_n)
des <- rep(NA, itr_n)
res <- matrix(rep(NA, itr_n*itr_n), itr_n, itr_n) # this is a result matric to store 
res[i, ] <- w #populating the row with info before we change w


for(i in 1:itr_n){
    v[i]<- w %*%  x[i,] #w[i,] was redundent since w is already a column vector
    y[i] <- if(v[i] >= 0) 1 else -1
    e[i] <- d[i] - y[i]
    des[i] <- if(d[i] == y[i]) 1 else 0
    res[i+1, ] <- w + (m*e[i]*x[i,]) #storing w in a res matrix
    w <- res[i+1, ] 
}
```

Comment: look at the changes that I have just made to the algorithm with the desired output. The product `v[i]<- w %*%  x[i,]` that you suggest is incorrect. The result must be a cartesian matrix product (1x1).